# Sass compiler can't see Compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have compass installed but when I try to watch the SASS file I get:

```
Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
```

Is there a way I should reference to compass?
(using Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Compass from the command line, you should be using its own watcher instead of Sass's.

```
compass watch
```

If you're within the context of another Ruby app, then you'll need to make sure the Compass gem is properly required.